# How does LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle) works

Tags: java, object, parent, substitution

The LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle) states that:
The principle defines that objects of a superclass shall be replaceable with objects of its subclasses without breaking the application.

E.g:

```
Vehicle BMW = new Car();
```

How does the above statement works, at memory level (how it works)?
The class "Car" was created to fulfill specific behavior that car has but a general vehicle lacks.

How can a "BMW's" object be referred to the vehicle class?

Comment: It's not a `BMW` object, it's a `Vehicle` variable named `BMW`.

Comment: A `Car` can be a `Vehicle`, but a `Vehicle` not necessarily is a `Car`, it could be a `Truck` for example.

Comment: that's okay and feel very natural when talking in plain English that a car is a vehicle it's obvious.

Comment: Can u explain the phenomenon of instantiating a variable of class vehicle but using a contructor of Car();

Answer (score 1):

LSP, simply put, is in regards to the substitutability of the variables and references you use. A common example is with the collections api:

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is okay, but suppose we have a list method:

```
public void printList(LinkedList<String> printedList) { ... }
```

Now, we cannot pass `ArrayList<String>` to the `LinkedList<String>` parameter, they're different types! However, the only actual functionality we require is not the specific quirks of `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`, but rather just the specific functions of `List` itself. So we write those in *substitutable ways*:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>(); //still an arraylist!

public void printList(List<String> printedList) { ... } //any list type
```

Now we can pass our parameter, as we are not unnecessarily bound to a subtype that we don't require the functionality of.

In terms of memory-level, these objects are still the same objects in heap memory, you simply refer to them as their supertype (and in fact you can downcast them if you know the type).

So using your example, you may have a case where any vehicle in existance has a color. So we have methods:

```
public class Vehicle {

    public Color getColor() { ... }
    public void setColor(Color color) { ... }

}
```

And in doing this, *any* subclass for `Vehicle` will have the color methods, but not the more specific methods in relation to say, `BMW` or `Car`. This is more relevant to inheritance than LSP however.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for such a detailed answer.

Comment: Second is that I'm new to learning oop>
And what I have understood about Classes and Objects is that.
Classes are to objects as Data types are to variables.
Pretty straight forward, but we create a child class to enhance the behavior and be more specific to some things.
The thing that I am unable to understand is that okay if we are using parent class as a reference because its natural but why are we using constructor of child class for initialization.

Comment: And last question is:
One LSP's application is that let say we have a list of Audio and Video objects extended from Media class and we can retrieve objects from list using Media class reference, but in first there will be some properties or some specific instance variable that will be missing in Media class, how we will handle that way.

Comment: Simply put with the example: `List` is an abstract type, and cannot be instantiated (think of it like an "incomplete" class, and think of classes like "blueprints" describing objects, with objects being the actual instances). In this case, we provide it a concrete type (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc), one that has implemented any of the missing behavior. For this specific reason `new List<>()` is invalid java.

Comment: As for the `Media` example, you have the `instanceof` operator to determine the type of the variable you are working with. `someList instanceof ArrayList` would return true, same for comparing to `List`, but not `LinkedList`. Once you've determined the type with `instanceof` you can then simply cast the variable and treat it like the subclass `((ArrayList<String>) someList).set(0, "test")`

Answer (score 0):

**LSP** says that when we will extend a class, the relation between subclass and super class must be **IS A**. In your example, Car **IS A** Vehicle. So when Car class extends Vehicle, there will be no violation of LSP.

In memory level, a Car object is created which is referred by Vehicle. And BMW reference will be able to access all public and protected method, instance variable of Vehicle.

Comment: but what's the meaning behind using a constructor Car();